# C++ operator << overload

Tags: c++, logging, operator-overloading

I have a 3rd party (logging) class that overloads the << operator. The client code using this logger class can use this by calling one of the pre-defined macros. As an example:

```
//logs can be filtered based on this module id string
LOGGER_INFO("MODULE_ID_STR") << "Logging at info level";
```

I'd like to extend this feature wherein the class/module using this 3rd party logger does not have to include the module id string each time. Meaning - the client code should set the module id string once and then be able to do this:

```
cLogger.INFO << "Logging at info level";
```

The above call should internally use the registered module id string registered earlier and then use that to make the actual 3rd party log call. So can this be done elegantly in C++ by overloading the << operator for each of the log levels.

Some additional details...I started out by doing this:

This is the class  that extends the functionality of the 3rd party logger:

```
class LoggerEx
{
public:
    LoggerEx(const std::string &moduleToLog)
    {
       m_ModuleID = moduleToLog;
    };
    virtual ~LoggerEx() {};

    class Debug
    {
      //overload the << operator (how to write this..??)
      LOGGER_INFO(m_ModuleID) << "Logging at info level";
    };

    class Info
    {
      //overload the << operator
    };
    //Note that there could be more such levels
    // (INFO, WARN, ERROR, TRACE, FATAL, etc).

public:
    Debug DEBUG;
    Info  INFO;

protected:
    std::string m_ModuleID

};
```

Some client code using the logger class should be allowed to do this...

```
class Xyz
{
public:
     Xyz() : l("Xyz")
     {}
     void doSomething()
     {
         l.DEBUG << "Doing something"; 
     }
protected:
     Logger l;
};
```

Another client class...

```
class Mno
{
public:
     Xyz() : l("Mno")
     {}

     void processSomething()
     {
         l.INFO << "Process something"; 
     }
protected:
     Logger l;
};
```

Since the original logger supports several data types (int, float, chars, std::string), will the above be the approach, or are there any other ideas/solutions to do this more elegantly in C++ without writing a full blown wrapper (or duplicating code) to the logger?

Thanks...

Comment: Are you asking how to overload an operator, or something else?

Comment: Yes and No. Yes - if overload is the solution. No if there are other possible solutions (like templates etc)
But how do I write the overload method << and still call the underlying (log) macro while using the module id string? Note that I don't want to write the overload method for all the different possible data types.

Comment: The most elegant and well-integrating approach would be using a standard output-stream, with additional facets for setting the warning level, log level and module name.  
Of course, that approach needs a custom streambuffer too.

Comment: Well, you can overload the operator, but make the overload a template...

Comment: Just overload the operator in the same way you already have it, but using a template for your input data type.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually harder than one might think, mostly because in a typical logging library, the `LOGGER_INFO` macro or its equivalents do more than just giving you a stream. Here's a typical macro from Boost:

```
#define BOOST_LOG_STREAM_WITH_PARAMS_INTERNAL(logger, rec_var, params_seq)\
    for (::boost::log::record rec_var = (logger).open_record((BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(params_seq))); !!rec_var;)\
        ::boost::log::aux::make_record_pump((logger), rec_var).stream()
```

A quick look at this code shows that it creates a new `record`, creates a `pump`, gets the `stream` from this pump, and your `<< "log text here" << " more log stuff"` calls actually operates on that stream. It is when the pump and record gets destructed, at the end of the statement, that the message actually get pushed out into a single log entry, which makes sense when you think of it - you'd expect `LOGGER_INFO(m_ModuleID) << "Logging at info level" << "more text";` to produce one log entry instead of two.

Thus a naive implementation like

```
class LoggerEx
{
public:
    LoggerEx(const std::string &moduleToLog) : Debug(moduleToLog)
    { }
    ~LoggerEx() {}

    class Debug
    {
      private:
          std::string m_ModuleID;
      public:
          Debug(const std::string &module) : m_ModuleID(module) {}
          template <typename T>
          const Debug & operator << (const T& thing_to_log) const {
              LOGGER_INFO(m_ModuleID) << thing_to_log;
              return *this;
          }
    };

public:
    Debug DEBUG;
};
```

will only work if you only use `<<` once per statement in your logging code.

One possible way of getting around it would be to use an internal stream to store the log-entry-in-making:

```
class LoggerEx
{
public:
    LoggerEx(const std::string &moduleToLog) : m_module(moduleToLog)
    { }
    ~LoggerEx() {}

    class Debug
    {
      private:
          std::string m_ModuleID;
          std::stringstream m_ss;
      public:
          Debug(const std::string &module) : m_ModuleID(module) {}
          Debug(const Debug &other) : m_ModuleID(other.m_ModuleID) {}
          ~Debug() { 
              std::string str = m_ss.str();
              if(!str.empty())
                  LOGGER_INFO(m_ModuleID) << str;
          }
          template <typename T>
          Debug & operator << (const T& thing_to_log) {
              m_ss << thing_to_log;
              return *this;
          }
    };

public:
    Debug DEBUG() { return Debug(m_module);}
private:
    std::string m_module;
};
```

It would be called like

```
l.DEBUG() << "Some stuff " << some_number << " some more stuff";
```

The idea is that the `DEBUG()` call produces a temporary object; your `operator <<` calls on that temporary object writes stuff into the `stringstream`, and at the end of the line, when the temporary object gets destructed, the things in the `stringstream` get pushed out to the logging library.

Comment: +1 I was away and needed much too long to deingeneer it down to something like this. Good work. Anyway, boost has a great logging library already doing all that.

Comment: I know StackOverflow says to avoid commenting with "thank yous" but I'm gonna be a rebel here.  Thank you!  I found this clever example very useful for removing the need for an "endl" delimiter for my own custom logging class :)